# HTML -jquery -json via ajax call - populate 2 web tables one on top of the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have 2 tables that I populate via 2 searches (mySQL-JSON-AJAX) based on the value of 2 input boxes.  The user enters a search item and click the corresponding button. it is all working except that when button1 (top table) is clicked first - data1 populates the top table as expected but then when button2 is clicked, data2 that is supposed to populate the bottom table get appended (to the right) in the top table.  BUT if i start with button2 to populate the bottom table and then populate the top table with button1 it is all working.  hopefully this make sense!
here an example how I populate the top table (bottom table is implemented the same way) by clicking button1 . How do I force data2 to go to the bottom table when data1 is already in the top table?

```
function processJSON1( data ) {                                               


var next_row_num = 1;                                                     


$.each( data.matches, function(i, item) {                                 
    var this_row_id = 'result_row_' + next_row_num++;                     
      //add data to table1                                                                                  
    $('<tr/>', { "id" : this_row_id } ).appendTo('#table1');              


    $('<td/>', { "text" : item.col1 } ).appendTo('#' + this_row_id);                                      
    $('<td/>', { "text" : item.col2 } ).appendTo('#' + this_row_id);                                   
    $('<td/>', { "text" : item.col3 } ).appendTo('#' + this_row_id);   

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the row id is not incrementing? have you tried logging out the row ids to make sure the .each is doing what you expect

Comment: the increments looks ok (data2 gets appended to the right of data1)... could it be an html issue since it is working when data2 is entered before data1?

Comment: maybe the first table is not being escaped properly. from your description, It's like the `<tr>` isn't being closed. I would run it, doing table one first then table two and when it goes to the right check the html to see where it lies. See if table one is being appended table one by mistake.

Comment: thanks for the input.  I find (sort of!) a way around it.  since when table2 is populated before table1, the data goes into the right table.  I still let the user populate table1 first, but when the user clicks button2 to populate table2, i first empty table1, populate table2, and populate 1 again (not very efficient).  but the issue with this approach is that the data seems at times to randomly populate either table2 or table1 (90% ok, 10% not ok) ???